# I cant access sub nodes for web scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, nodes, screen, rvest

I am trying to scrape players information from website using the following code:

```
#install required packages
if(!require(pacman))install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load('rvest', 'stringi', 'dplyr', 'tidyr', 'measurements', 'reshape2','foreach','doParallel','raster','curl','httr','Iso')

profile_detail<-read_html('https://www.pgatour.com/players/player.01006.john-adams.html#profile')%>%html_node("[class='s-header__bottom']")%>%html_children()
```

But this code is not giving me the desired result. Instead, getting one one node:

```
[1] <div class="s-header__no-data">No additional profile information available</div>
```

Not sure how to access the div class of 's-col'

Here is the snippet of the players info I want to extract:

Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For me, when I go to that page in the browser it also says 'No additional profile information available'. Are you logged in or something like that?

Comment: @Bas Yeah, that is what i am getting as well because that is what is under that particular node. But the problem is that that is not what i want to scrape, instead the information about the players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `div.s-col` in `html_nodes` :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.pgatour.com/players/player.06197.michael-allen.html'

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('div.s-col') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  gsub('\\h+', ' ', ., perl = TRUE) %>%
  cat
```

I am not sure how you want your final expected output to look but this returns :

```
 #Michael Allen 
 #Full Name
 
 
 #6 ft, 0 in
 #183 cm
 #Height
 
 
 #195 lbs
 #89 kg
 #Weight
 
 
 #January 31, 1959
 #Birthday
 
 
 #61
 #AGE
 
 
 #San Mateo, California
 #Birthplace
 
 
 #Scottsdale, Arizona
 #Residence
 
 
 #Wife, Cynthia; Christy (12/8/93), Michelle (6/3/97)
 #Family
 
 
 #University of Nevada (1982, Horticulture) 
 #College
 
 
 #1984
 #Turned Pro
 
 
 #16,963,593
 #Career Earnings
 
 
 #Paradise Valley, AZ, United States
 #City Plays From
```

Note that some of the players don't have their personal information on the page.

Comment: thank you for your help. Is there a way to store the values in dataframe or something?

Comment: There is no fixed structure of the text to turn this information into dataframe easily. Perhaps after getting all this information in a list you can use some kind of regex to capture each information individually and put it in a dataframe.